# Realm Sync swift example

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, realm

Hi all im trying to create an ios app that sync data using Realm Object server
but there is something im missing

i installed corretly Realm object server  on my server (remote)
i can access the dashboard correctly

i can login with Syncuser

but i have problem syncing data..  when i open the app i login the user but after that ( im unable to sync anyting )

i searched online for a full example but without success
any one can suggest a simple and easy example for use realm sync with swift?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide more details? Can you show your code around using Realm and login? Also can you show the Realm Object Server's log?

Answer (score 1):

This is my actual implementation for a chat app using RealmSwift. I used a model object called Message defined below:

```
class Message: Object {
    dynamic var userId = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var text = ""
    dynamic var dateCreated = NSDate()
}
```

Next I used created a controller for sending and sync messages:

```
// Instance variables
var messages: Results<Message>!
var token: NotificationToken!
var configuration: Realm.Configuration!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Your viewDidLoad implementation

    self.setupRealm()

}
```

Next the setup methods for Realm. As mentioned in [Real Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#opening-a-synchronized-realm), if a Realm has read-only permissions, then you must use the `asyncOpen` API as described in Asynchronously Opening Realms. Opening a `read-only` Realm without `asyncOpen` will cause an error.

```
private func setupRealm() {

    let serverURL = URL(string: "http://your.server.ip:9080")!
    let credentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: "example@mail.com", password: "password")

    SyncUser.logIn(with: credentials, server: serverURL) { user, error in
        if let user = user {
            let syncURL = URL(string: "realm://your.server.ip:9080/~/Message")!
            let syncConfig = SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: syncURL)
            self.configuration = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: syncConfig)
            self.setupDataSource()

        } else if let error = error {
            // handle error
            debugPrint("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

}

private func setupDataSource() {

    Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: self.configuration) { realm, error in
        if let realm = realm {
            // Realm successfully opened, with all remote data available
            self.messages = realm.objects(Message.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "dateCreated", ascending: true)
            self.token = self.messages.addNotificationBlock({ (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
                debugPrint("Message update event")
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            })

        } else if let error = error {
            // Handle error that occurred while opening or downloading the contents of the Realm
            debugPrint("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

}

deinit {
    self.token?.stop()
}
```

Finally the `sendMessage()` method that I use to send the message:

```
func sendMessage(id: String, name: String, text: String) {

    let message = Message()
    message.userId = id
    message.name = name
    message.text = text
    message.dateCreated = NSDate()

    Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: self.configuration) { realm, error in
        if let realm = realm {
            // Realm successfully opened, with all remote data available
            try! realm.write() {
                realm.add(message)
            }
        } else if let error = error {
            // Handle error that occurred while opening or downloading the contents of the Realm
            debugPrint("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it helps!
Bye!